# Using org-capture-templates with mu4e

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to create a template using org-capture templates when using mu4e. When viewing a message in mu4e:view mode, I can call org-capture-templates with a keystroke and then add a reminder in a file with a link to the message. Something like this:

```
* NEXT Respond to Person A on Message Subject 
SCHEDULED: <2013-06-22 Sat>
[2013-06-22 Sat 22:05]
Email subject linked to mu4e message
```

Here's the template in my .emacs:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
(quote (("r" "respond" entry (file "~/refile.org")
"* NEXT Respond to %:from on %:subject\nSCHEDULED: %t\n%U\n%a\n\n" 
 :clock-in t :clock-resume t :immediate-finish t))))
```

But the variables in section 9.1.3.2 of the orgmode official manual are not set in mu4e. My guess is it should be set in the following function in org-mu4e.el. See the 3 lines marked by a comment I added, but this does not solve the problem. The link (%a) gets initialized, but not :to, :from and :subject.

If I debug, I can see the function call to org-store-link-props looks like this:

```
org-store-link-props(:type "mu4e" :from (("Person Name" . "person@email.whatever"))
:to (("Me Surname" . "me@here.com")) :subject "Re: Subject of Email" 
:message-id "message-id")
```

However, the template evaluates to:

```
* NEXT Respond to %:from on %:subject
SCHEDULED: <2013-06-23 Sun>
[2013-06-23 Sun 21:08]
```

Thanks for the help - this is the final function that works for me:

```
(defun org-mu4e-store-link ()
"Store a link to a mu4e query or message."
(cond
 ;; storing links to queries
 ((eq major-mode 'mu4e-headers-mode)
  (let* ((query (mu4e-last-query))
      desc link)
(org-store-link-props :type "mu4e" :query query)
(setq
  desc (concat "mu4e:query:" query)
  link desc)
(org-add-link-props :link link :description desc)
link))
  ;; storing links to messages
((eq major-mode 'mu4e-view-mode)
  (let* ((msg  (mu4e-message-at-point))
     (msgid   (or (plist-get msg :message-id) "<none>"))
     (from (car (car (mu4e-message-field msg :from))))
     (to (car (car (mu4e-message-field msg :to))))
     (subject (mu4e-message-field msg :subject))
     link)
   (setq link (concat "mu4e:msgid:" msgid))
   (org-store-link-props :type "mu4e" :link link
             :message-id msgid)
   (setq link (concat "mu4e:msgid:" msgid))
   (org-store-link-props 
    :type "mu4e" :from from :to to :subject subject
          :message-id msgid)

   (org-add-link-props :link link
           :description (funcall org-mu4e-link-desc-func msg))
   link))))

(org-add-link-type "mu4e" 'org-mu4e-open)
(add-hook 'org-store-link-functions 'org-mu4e-store-link)
```

Comment: Okay, made some progress. Seems like mu4e-message-field returns a the emails as (("Name Surname" . "name@email.com")). So if I change that to a string with something like two calls of car it sort of works, unless the from field in the mail doesn't have a name and email, like "Name Surname <name@email.com>". Not an elegant solution at all, but works for now.

Comment: Another way of going from a list of lists to a string would work better?

Comment: If you look at section 'Message functions' in the manual (it seems SO doesn't let me format this as something very readable...):

      The contact fields (To, From, Cc, Bcc) are lists of cons-pairs ‘(name . email)’;
      ‘name’ may be ‘nil’.  So, for example:
     
              (mu4e-message-field some-msg :to)
              ;; => (("Jack" . "jack@example.com") (nil . "foo@example.com"))

Comment: @cheese where you able to get this setup up and running properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(setq from
   (let ((first (car (mu4e-message-field-at-point :from))))
     (if (car first)
       (format "%s <%s>" (car first) (cdr first))
       (cdr first))))
```